# Auth::check in lithium with uploadify

Tags: uploadify, lithium

I have a controller which process uploaded files by uploadify. The problem is that the `Auth::check('default')` always return *null*. So I can't check if the user is logged in and authorized to upload.

```
class UploadController extends \app\controllers\AppController {

    // this works perfect, the auth configuration is printed out
    public function index() {
        $auth = Auth::check('default');
        print_r($auth);
    }

    // this doesnt work
    public function uploadify() {
        $auth = Auth::check('default');
        print_r($auth); // always empty!
        ...
    }
}
```

The `uploadify` function is called via uploadify. I tried to trace the problem back but I ended in `StaticObject::_filter` where the following if statement returns true:

```
if (!isset(static::$_methodFilters[$class][$method])) {...}
```

This differs from the call of `index()` where the *if*-statement isn't executed. But I have no idea what's done there.

Comment: With only this piece of code, it seems very hard to help you. Try #li3 on irc.freenode.net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thx to #li3 i got this work with http://www.uploadify.com/forums/discussion/43/using-sessions-tricking-basic-authentication/p1

In the view i used the scriptData:

```
'scriptData': { 'PHPSESSID': '<?php echo(session_id()); ?>'},
```

and in the Controller:

```
public function uploadify() {
  $id = $_POST['PHPSESSID'];
  session_id($id);
  session_start();
  $auth = Auth::check('default');
  if ($auth == null) {
      return $this->response->status = array('code' => 401, 'message' => 'Unauthorized');
  }
  ...
}
```